# How to allow only a single instance of a widget android

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

I want to allow the addition of a single widget, I tried to put a boolean flag and i have:

Inside WidgetConfig:

```
public final static String ADDED_KEY = "IsAdded";
public static boolean isAdded = false;
```

onCreate (inside WidgetConfig)

```
isAdded = prefs.getBoolean(ADDED_KEY, false);       
    if (isAdded){
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Only one Widget", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
 [...]
editor.putBoolean(ADDED_KEY, true); //disable adding here
editor.commit();
```

Inside WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider

```
public void onDisabled(Context context) {

    super.onDisabled(context);
    [...]
//cancel alarm
   configEditor.putBoolean(WidgetConfig.ADDED_KEY, false); //enable adding here
    configEditor.commit();
}

public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds){
super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
//I should not need this if there is only one widget
}
```

But it does not always work.
How can I do? Thanks

Comment: isAdded = prefs.getBoolean(ADDED_KEY, false);       <--- are you aware that the "false" here is just the defaultValue if there is no value to retrieve from preferences?

Comment: that is the first command when starting the configuration of the widget
if the widget is added for the first time isAdded has no value, then the default is false
after adding the value changes in true at the line "//disable adding here"
and then is expected to return false when I delete the widget (onDisabled)
sometimes it works, sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

Get the Ids of your added widget(s) from the AppWidgetManager directly and check how many have already been added in your Configuration Activity.

```
int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppWidgetIds(
            new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_WIDGET.class));

    if(ids.length > 0){
        //do not add the widget
    }else{
        //add the widget
    }
```

That's what I usually do to check if there are any instances of my widget.

Comment: That returns old widget ids. When you remove the widget and try to get app widget ids, it returns that removed widget id so this logic doesn't work as intended.